# SQLite update query is not updating table data with phonegap3.1

Tags: sqlite, cordova, android-sqlite

I am new user for SQLite. I am using phonegap3.1 foe android. I have an issue while updating user table. Below is the code that I am using:

```
var db = window.openDatabase("riazdb", "1.0", "Demo", 200000);
var userName = "user1";
db.transaction(function(tx) {                       
  tx.executeSql('UPDATE user SET auto_login = "true" WHERE name = ?', [userName], userUpdateSuccess, userUpdateError);
}, userUpdateError);

function userUpdateSuccess(tx, results) {           
  console.log("affected rows : "+results.rowsAffected);             
}

function userUpdateError(err) {
  console.log("userUpdateError");
}
```

I am getting response as a success with results.rowsAffected = 1.
Can somebody tell me that what am I doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Is your data getting updated ?

Comment: Thanks for response.No, The data is not getting updated.

Comment: Try this                                                          var Test= "true";                                     tx.executeSql('UPDATE user SET auto_login = ? WHERE name = ?', [test,userName], userUpdateSuccess, userUpdateError);
}, userUpdateError);

Comment: This is also giving same response. When I execute query it returns success with results.rowsAffected = 1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same scenario.

Take a look in your onSuccess callback. If there is an unhanded exception thrown from your onSuccess handler, you will see the success happen, you will see rowsAffected == 1. However I suspect that the exception in the success handler causes phonegap to never WRITE the results to the table.

HTH